Graphql return null values
Schema.graphqls
type Query {
    getGoogleMedia: [GoogleMedia] @resolver(class: "Test\\LocationData\\Model\\Resolver\\GoogleMediaResolver")
}
type GoogleMedia {
    image_view_all_link: String
    images: GooglePhotos
    video_view_all_link: String
    videos: GoogleVideos
}
type GooglePhotos {
    id: Int
    review_id: String
    image: String
}
type GoogleVideos {
    id: Int
    review_id: String
    video_link: String
}


GoogleMediaResolver
$connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
        $viewAllImagesLink = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('google_location_data/google_photos_api/google_photos_view_all_url', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        $viewAllVideosLink = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('google_location_data/google_videos_api/google_videos_view_all_url', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        $tableNamePhotos = $connection->getTableName('test_google_photos');
        $tableNameVideos = $connection->getTableName('test_google_video');
        // Fetch photos
        $selectPhotos = $connection->select()
            ->from($tableNamePhotos, ['id', 'review_id', 'image'])
            ->where('show_in_website = ?', 1);
        $photos = $connection->fetchAll($selectPhotos);

        // Fetch videos
        $selectVideos = $connection->select()
            ->from($tableNameVideos, ['id', 'review_id', 'video_link'])
            ->where('show_in_website = ?', 1);
        $videos = $connection->fetchAll($selectVideos);

        // Format the response
        $response = [
            'image_view_all_link' => $viewAllImagesLink,
            'images' => $photos,
            'video_view_all_link' => $viewAllImagesLink,
            'videos' => $videos,
        ];
        // print_r($response);exit;
        return $response;

but I am getting null.

If I do print_r($response) I am getting the correct values.

Can you share the full file for "GoogleMediaResolver" seems something wrong in it

I figured it out. This issue occur when the return value does not satisfy the structure we defined.

Use xdebug to identify the issue. I believe no one can tell the problem unless they have access to details like what is the resolver class and how is the complete request flow. I would advise using logging (if xdebug is not possible) to log the data in the resolver and see what value you get. Log other relevant data to understand the issue better.

Here is the correct Schema structure
type Query {
    getGoogleMedia: [GoogleMedia] @resolver(class: "Test\\LocationData\\Model\\Resolver\\GoogleDataResolver")
}


type GoogleVideos {
    id: Int
    review_id: String
    video_link: String
}

type GooglePhotos {
    view_all_link: String
    data: [GooglePhoto]
}

type GoogleVideos {
    view_all_link: String
    data: [GoogleVideo]
}
type GooglePhoto {
    id: Int
    review_id: String
    image: String
}

type GoogleVideo {
    id: Int
    review_id: String
    video_link: String
}

type getGoogleMedia {
    photos: GooglePhotos
    videos: GoogleVideos
}

